# Ruby: how to convert IP address from hex string to human readable?

Tags: ruby

Not able to find it, apologize in advance if duplicate.

I want to convert address like,

```
0000000000000000FFFF00000B79290A
```

into human readable form. Note, although it is IPv6, it is actually IPv4 address embedded, so more preferably to have it converted to like:

```
10.41.121.11
```

I read this type of address from /proc/net/tcp, and would like to parse it.

Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. What have you tried? Have you looked through the built-in [IPAddr](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.2.2/libdoc/ipaddr/rdoc/index.html) class? How about the [NetAddr](http://netaddr.rubyforge.org/classes/NetAddr.html) gem? We expect you to show us what you've tried, where you've searched, and at least explain why things didn't meet your needs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ruby comes with the IPAddr class which can parse IPv4 and IPv6 strings into objects. There's also [NetAddr](http://netaddr.rubyforge.org/classes/NetAddr/CIDR.html) which is very powerful. Use the pre-invented wheels when possible as they're well tested and include useful methods:

```
require 'ipaddr'
IPAddr.new "[#{'0000000000000000FFFF00000B79290A'.scan(/.{4}/).join(':')}]"
#<IPAddr: IPv6:0000:0000:0000:0000:ffff:0000:0b79:290a/ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff>
```

It's necessary to convert the string to colon-delimited fields, and wrapping it in `[...]` tells IPAddr to consider it an IPv6 address:

```
'0000000000000000FFFF00000B79290A'.scan(/.{4}/)
=> [
    [0] "0000",
    [1] "0000",
    [2] "0000",
    [3] "0000",
    [4] "FFFF",
    [5] "0000",
    [6] "0B79",
    [7] "290A"
]

'0000000000000000FFFF00000B79290A'.scan(/.{4}/).join(':')
=> "0000:0000:0000:0000:FFFF:0000:0B79:290A"
```

Using NetAddr:

```
NetAddr::CIDR.create('0000000000000000FFFF00000B79290A'.scan(/.{4}/).join(':'))
=> #<NetAddr::CIDRv6:0x007fd4971c34f0 @ip=18446462598925330698, @version=6, @address_len=128, @all_f=340282366920938463463374607431768211455, @netmask=340282366920938463463374607431768211455, @network=18446462598925330698, @hostmask=0, @tag={}, @wildcard_mask=340282366920938463463374607431768211455>
```

Comment: you have a typo it's `require 'ipaddr'`

Comment: Gotta love spelling-check. Thanks.

Comment: Enclosing the string in square brackets does not seem to be required.

Comment: I don't think it's required, the docs say it's optional, but it seems to be an added hint that it's an IPv6 address.

Comment: Thanks, I think there is still at least one mile to go. "to_s" just remove the leading zeros: "::ffff:0:b79:290a", but I like "10.41.121.11". It seems I can just manipulate at the string level and the library is not that helpful.